# Returning value from callback in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

So in my app I have 2 players in a game. Player 1 is assigned either heads or tails, and then player 2 is to be assigned the side that player 1 is not. i.e. if player 1 is heads, then player 2 is tails, and vice versa.

To check to see which side player 1 is before assigning a side to player 2, I have a callback setup to get which side player 1 has been assigned. And the callback looks like this.

```
public interface Player1SideCallback {
    void onCallback(String side);
}

private void player1Side(final Player1SideCallback callback) {
        FCGames.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                HomePage.getCurrentGameID(new HomePage.CallbackID() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String currentGameID) {
                            String player1Side = dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("HeadsOrTails").getValue().toString();
                            callback.onCallback(player1Side);
                        }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}
```

It's a pretty basic callback.

Now, I am when a player clicks the `join` button they are assigned to the game as player 2 using this snippet:

```
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, openGames, new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.OnButtonClickListener() {
        @Override public void onButtonClick(String id, final int position) {
            String gameID = openGames.get(position);


            second = new User(userName, 0, getSide2(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), gameID, false);


            gm.setUser2(second);
            FCGames.child(gameID).child("user2").setValue(second);
            HomePage.setCurrentGame(gameID);
            HomePage.setUserPosition(2);
        }});
enter code here
```

As you can see, I have left line spaces around the variable `second` because that is where the new player is actually being created. And where it says `getSide2()` it is assigning a side to the player 2.

But, I am struggling to get this right. I call my callback in a method called `getSide2()` to try to properly assign the right side to user 2

```
private String getSide2() {
    player1Side(new Player1SideCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(String side) {
            if(side.equals("Heads")) {
                String side2 = "Tails";
            } else {
                String side2 = "Heads";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So I want to assign the player2 the side with the variable `side2` but I am not sure how to return this value from a method using a callback.

How can I use this type of logic to properly assign the correct side to user 2?

Comment: why you have putted callback code to method its should be global or implemented by class level.

Comment: @ChetanJoshi because I only want the value to be calledback whenever I need it to be (in this case when I call the method). How can I use the callback differently so that I can just get the value from the callback when I need it?

Comment: its not working as you think , because whenever callback comes method will not be triggering it self. And as you want callback only be called when onSuccess() called from your first code.

Comment: @ChetanJoshi Okay so say I place the callback right above my `adapter` in the onCreate() method. How would I pull the value `side2` out and then use it in my `adapter` to make user2?

Comment: Not in OnCreate() , its no need to add callback code under any block of code its working fine with out any block OR you simply implement Player1SideCallback by MyRecyclerViewAdapter class and override its method at class . level

Comment: @CoderKlipto did you manage to get a solution to this?